# Pass data from Child to Parent in React Three Fiber onCollide function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-three-fiber

I need to pass the `event` inside `onCollide` function to the **parent component**. I have tried with `props.handleCollide(e);` but I got an error: *props.handleCollide is not a function*. If it helps, I'm using **React Three Fiber**, a React library for Three.js.

**Sphere.js**

```js
const Sphere = (props) => {
  const [ref, api] = useSphere((index) => ({
    mass: 1,
    onCollide: (e) => {
      // I need to pass the event 'e' to Parent Component
      props.handleCollide(e);
    },
    position: props.position,
    ...props,
  }));

  return (
    <mesh castShadow position={props.position} ref={ref}>
      <sphereGeometry args={props.args} />
      <meshStandardMaterial color={props.color} />
    </mesh>
  );
}

export default Sphere;
```

Another attempt was to do `props.event = e` but I got other error: *Cannot add property event, object is not extensible*.

The main goal is to do something like this:

```js
<Sphere position={[0, 3, 0]} args={[0.5]} color="purple" handleCollide={handleCollide} />
```

And then catch the event and do the logic.

Comment: can you please question to include handleCollide definition?

Comment: Also if you can provide sandbox link that would be great.

Comment: I don't have `handleCollide` defined in the child because I understand that I pass it through props. Am I right?

Comment: yes, it is totally fine. But I was curios about what the function definition is in the parent.

Comment: also there is no purpose of spreading ...props in useSphere hook at last.

Comment: The main purpose in the parent is to catch the event and then do an if/else statement, nothing relevant. The problem is that I can't pass the event to parent and don't know why.

Comment: The error: props.handleCollide is not a function.   means that there is no such thing like handleCollide in props.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but it's the same approach that `onClick={handleCollision}` when you pass the `handleCollision` function through the *props* with no declaration in the child component.

Comment: what is handleCollision in the parent? have you defined that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247330/discussion-between-jgcarrillo-and-talha-fayyaz).